# Error Message in Console: needs its JSON updated because the app PI changed

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

When trying to get universal links working I am getting this error and I have no idea what it means

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
            "appID": "5574HK487X.io.xxxxx.starter",
            "paths": [ "*" ],
             "appIDs": [ "5574HK487X.io.xxxxx.starter" ],
             "components": [
               {
                  "/": "*",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL "
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   },
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": []
   },
    "appclips": {
        "apps": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: I noticed the same message before it starts downloading the file. I think this just means that the cached version of the file on the device is outdated or missing, so it will be downloaded from the CDN or server.

Comment: I got Universal Links working but these messages still show up in the console. They're probably not the reason why Universal Links are not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that

- `Content-Type` is `application/json; charset=utf-8` and
- make sure that `Content-Encoding` is `gzip`

Comment: Where do you set these values?